# Common terms for encouragement and cheering?

Tags: modismos, diferencias-regionales, deportes

In many languages there is a common term or phrase used to encourage people in different contexts including sports, school and work.

In Japanese, for example, there is *ganbatte!* ("do your best"). In Chinese, there's *jia you!* ("add oil"). In English, the most common terms seem to be variations of *Go!*, such as *Go team!* or *Let's go!*

Is there a term or terms like this in the Spanish-speaking world to cheer on competitors or encourage high performance during tests, projects or other events?

Comment: In line with "Go team!", your safest bet is "¡Vamos equipo!" for a team, or just "vamos {name}". It really depends on the country. There are a lot of Spanish speaking countries and different contextual meanings.

Comment: Como dijo Homer Simpson: "¡Si pierdes, te echamos de la familia!"

Answer (score 10):

With slightly different meanings and applicable to different contexts:

¡Venga!, ¡vamos!, ¡anda!, ¡ándale!, ¡órale!, ¡dale!, ¡ánimo!, ¡aúpa!, ¡corre!...

Comment: Some of these are more region-dependent than others. Not sure if there's any Spanish-speaking place in which `¡vamos!` sounds off - but `¡venga!` would sound off in Argentina, among others.

Comment: Yes. As always, a double entry table term/country is needed to specify where each one is preferred. Possibly a nice collaborative answer.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the first one that comes to my mind is a literal translation of the English term "Go! / Let's go!": **¡Vamos!**

The first person plural form of the present of the verb "ir" (to go) is used especifically to exhort, as you can verify in a [specific entry of the DLE](https://dle.rae.es/vamos)

> **vamos**
>
> 1. expr. U. para exhortar.

where expr.U means expression used.

> 1. Expression used to exhort.

Comment: I’ve heard *¡Dale!* used a lot in this context in Cuba

Comment: I've heard _¡Eso!_ at football matches.  Also here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXnjy5YlDwk&t=82s

Comment: @hcbowman "Eso" means "that". Cheering "¡Eso!" is like cheering "That's it!". It makes sense when they're doing well so they keep at it, but maybe not when they're doing badly.